# MUX for receiving 1MHz ultrasonic signal from multiple transducers

Tags: multiplexer, ultrasound

I have one ultrasonic transducer that is connected to high voltage Pulser (1-2MHz), I want to detect the ultrasonic signal generated by this transducer with other multiple transducers (~16). I have an electronic device that is able to receive analog signal (amplify+filter+ADC) **from only one transducer**. I am looking for a MUX that will allow receiving the analog signal (typically <500mV) from the 16 transducers sequentially (ADC is set at ~10MHz, pulse repetition is set at ~1-20kHz).
**What are the design considerations and MUX parameters that shall be taken into account while selecting a suitable MUX for this purpose?**

Please note that I am looking only for a low voltage MUX, as the high voltage circuit is separated from the receiving circuit.

Comment: Questions about recommendation of specific part numbers are off topic here. You can solve your problem using the parametric search of any major online distributor of chips.

Comment: @VladimirCravero - thank you for your comment. I rephrased the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The selection of the MUX will depend on the key parameters that you are designing to maximise/minimise.

If your goal is to maximise SNR, SINAD or minimise phase error you will need different mix of parameters.

- For SNR maximising, you'll need to match impedance to ensure energy transfer and minimise cross-talk between channels.
- For SINAD, you'll need to consider the bandwidth of the MUX as well to minimise distortion.
- For phase error you'll also need to consider electrical TX/RX impedance matching. For details on this - if you are not already familiar with this topic - you can look [here (p65/68)](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/bitstream/11303/6325/4/hamouda_assia.pdf) or search for ultrasonic reciprocity (often mentionned in flow meter litterature).

You will also need to consider how the Coff and Con parameters aggregate when considering your impedance matching